# Controlar ordem do retorno de cURL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, libcurl

Estou a fazer um checador de *proxys* colocando uma lista de *proxys* no `textarea` e o código me retorna na tela 1 por 1 a baixo do outro se funcionam ou não. Está quase tudo pronto, o único problema é que não importa a ordem em que a lista de *proxy* esteja, sempre os *proxys* "#DIE" são exibidos antes dos "#LIVE"; se eu tenho uma lista com 5 *proxys* que funcionam e 5 que não funcionam não importando a ordem em que estejam no `textarea`, sempre os "#DIE" serão exibidos primeiro. Desejo que os resultados sejam exibidos na ordem em que os *proxys* foram colocados no `textarea`, mas como eu faço isso ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> chk </title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      function enviar(){
        var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
        var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
        var index = 0;
        linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){

          setTimeout(

            function(){
              $.ajax({
                url: 'chkp.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: "bin=" + value,
                success: function(resultado){
                $('#oi').html($('#oi').html() + resultado + "<br>");
              }
            })

          }, 10 * index);

        index = index + 1;

        })
      }
  </script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<textarea name="bin" placeholder="PROXY|PORTA" id="bin_id" rows="10" cols="40">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="testar" onclick="enviar();"></input>
<br>
<div id="oi" name="oi">
<p></p>
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo PHP:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

if(!empty($_POST["proxy"])){
$proxylist = substr($_POST['proxy'], 0, 90);
$proxy = explode("|", $proxy)[0];
$port = explode("|", $proxy)[1];
explode("|", $proxy)[2];



 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "host.com/prpxytest");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_proxy=' . urlencode($proxy) . '&_port=' . urlencode($port));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$dados = curl_exec($ch);

$q = explode('</i>', $dados);

$sal = $q[4];

$msg = ' ';

if(strpos($sal, "Sair") !== false){
    $msg = "<b><font color='green'>#LIVE $proxy | $port </font></b>";
}else{
    $msg = "<b><font color='red'>#DIE $proxy | $port </font></b>";
}

echo $msg;


}else{ echo 'erro'; }
?>
```

Comment: Para cada proxy na textarea o script mostrado é executado?

Comment: Como você executa este *script*?

Comment: Sim isso cada linha tem um proxy e a porta separados por |

Comment: O script e executado por um ajax jquery que faz todas a requisicão das linhas

Comment: Então seu problema não esta no PHP, mas sim no jQuery. O que acontece é que os testes que falham provavelmente geram os resultados antes daqueles que não falham, exibindo-os, assim, por primeiro. Visto que não requisições assíncronas, esta ordem nunca será garantida.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta com a parte que faz as requisições

Comment: Uma solução seria criar uma função recursiva que faz requisições assíncronas de forma sequencial, mas sinceramente eu não vejo motivo algum para fazer isso. Qual é a real necessidade de se obter o resultado em tal ordem?

Comment: Para organização das informações, tbm desejaria se possivel que ficasse dentro de iframes diferentes os resultados positivos e negativos e que as linhas de ambos fossem contadas e exibidas na tela, exemplo: (90 proxys vivos) 2 iframe (100 proxys mortos)

Comment: Porque editou a pergunta desta forma?

Comment: Ola pode me ajudar com este erro de retorno ?

Comment: Se é uma nova questão uma pouco desvida da questão acima deve criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: E por quê dois iframes? Não bastariam dois elementos na própria página? O que você quer fazer não parece fazer muito sentido.

Comment: Quero duas listas uma com a lista dos proxys mortos outra com os vivos que tenha a barra lateral para rolar para baixo

Comment: Dois pequenos frames com os resultados distintos

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que você explicou, o que você pretende fazer são várias requisições assíncronas de forma sequencial. Particularmente eu não vejo motivo algo para fazer isso, mas uma solução é implementar uma função recursiva que é sempre chamada no evento `success` da requisição anterior. Por exemplo, digamos que iremos fazer a requisição para as seguintes URLs:

```
const URLs = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
];
```

Criamos, então, uma função que recebe uma lista de URLs como entrada e faz as requisições de forma sequencial:

```
function asyncSequentialRequests(urls) {

  if (urls.length > 0) {

    let url = urls.shift();

    $.ajax({
      'url': url,
      'method': 'get',
      'dataType': 'json',
      'success': data => {
        console.log(`A url ${url} retornou ${data.length} resultados.`);
        asyncSequentialRequests(urls);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Desta forma, quando quiser iniciar as requisições, basta invocar a função:

```
asyncSequentialRequests(URLs);
```

O resultado será:

```
"A url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts retornou 100 resultados."
"A url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments retornou 500 resultados."
"A url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums retornou 100 resultados."
"A url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos retornou 5000 resultados."
"A url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos retornou 200 resultados."
"A url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users retornou 10 resultados."
```

Que condiz com os [valores informados no site](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com), na exata ordem que foram colocadas as URLs. Para o seu caso, basta gerar a lista de URLs dinamicamente, como já faz e adaptar a função `success`, lembrando de fazer a recursividade chamando a própria função em `success`. Para adicionar um elemento no final de outro, você pode utilizar o `append` do jQuery.

```js
const URLs = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
];

function asyncSequentialRequests(urls) {
  
  if (urls.length > 0) {
    
    let url = urls.shift();
    
    $.ajax({
      'url': url,
      'method': 'get',
      'dataType': 'json',
      'success': data => {
        console.log(`A url ${url} retornou ${data.length} resultados.`);
        asyncSequentialRequests(urls);
      }
    });
    
  }
  
}

asyncSequentialRequests(URLs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```